opening an image by clicking on the image
I want it to open full screen when you click on an image. How do I do this? I've tried all the options


.product-card-container {   display: flex;   gap: 0.5rem;   padding: 0.5rem;   border: 1px solid green;   justify-content: space-evenly; }  .product-card {   display: flex;   flex-direction: column;   justify-content: center;   width: 200px;   padding: 0 0.4rem;   row-gap: 0.5rem;   border: 1px solid black; }  .product-card > img {   object-fit: cover;   width: 100%;   height: 200px; }  .product-info {   /* Use this for growing an element to 100% width or height inside of a flex container */   flex-grow: 1 }  .nft{   user-select:none;   max-width: 300px;   margin: 2rem;   border: 1px solid #ffffff22;   background-color: #282c34;   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(40,44,52,1) 0%, rgba(17,0,32,.5) 100%);   box-shadow: 0 7px 20px 5px #00000088;   border-radius: .7rem;   backdrop-filter: blur(7px);   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px);   overflow: hidden;   transition: .5s all;   .wrapper li{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin: 10px 5px; }   hr{     width: 100%;     border: none;     border-bottom: 1px solid #88888855;     margin-top: 0;   }   ins{     text-decoration: none;   }   .main{     display: flex;     flex-direction: column;     width: 90%;     padding: 1rem;     color: #c572e6;     .tokenImage{       border-radius: .5rem;       max-width: 100%;       height: 250px;       object-fit: cover;     }     .description{         min-height: 100px;   max-height: 100px;       margin: .5rem 0;       color: #a89ec9;     }     .tokenInfo{       display: flex;       justify-content: space-between;       align-items: center;       .price{         display: flex;         align-items: center;         color: #ee83e5;         font-weight: 700;         ins{           margin-left: -.3rem;           margin-right: .5rem;         }       }       .duration{         display: flex;         align-items: center;         color: #a89ec9;         margin-right: .2rem;         ins{           margin: .5rem;           margin-bottom: .4rem;         }       }     }     .creator{       display: flex;       align-items: center;       margin-top: .2rem;       margin-bottom: -.3rem;       ins{         color: #a89ec9;         text-decoration: none;       }       .wrapper{         display: flex;         align-items: center;         border: 1px solid #ffffff22;         padding: .3rem;         margin: 0;         margin-right: .5rem;         border-radius: 100%;         box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #000000aa;         img{           border-radius: 100%;           border: 1px solid #ffffff22;           width: 2rem;           height: 2rem;           object-fit: cover;           margin: 0;         }       }     }   }   ::before{     position: fixed;     content: "";     box-shadow: 0 0 100px 40px #ffffff08;     top: -10%;     left: -100%;     transform: rotate(-45deg);     height: 60rem;     transition: .7s all;   }   &:hover{     border: 1px solid #ffffff44;     box-shadow: 0 7px 50px 10px #000000aa;     transform: scale(1.015);     filter: brightness(1.3);     ::before{       filter: brightness(.5);       top: -100%;       left: 200%;     }   } }  .bg{   position: fixed;   top: 50%;   left: 50%;   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   h1{     font-size: 20rem;     filter: opacity(0.5);   } }
 <div class="container">
 <div class="nft" onclick="addProd('11', products)" class="card" >
        <div class='main'>
          <img class='tokenImage' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/м1.jpg') }}" alt="NFT" />
          <h2>123</h2>
          <p class='description'>123</p>
          <div class='tokenInfo'>
            <div class="price">
              <ins>◘</ins>
              <p>499 Руб</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>




A nice, simple way to do it is just to wrap a link around the image pointing to its location in your file structure, so that clicking the image open the image in its own page. The user does have to click the back button afterwards, though.

https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

By full screen do you mean show the image in full screen? And please show us what you have tried.

You can use requestFullScreen


img.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  let elem = ev.target
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    elem.requestFullscreen().catch((err) => {
      alert(
        `Error attempting to enable fullscreen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`,
      );
    });
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
})
<img id="img" src="https://picsum.photos/150" style="display:block">




Sadly doesn’t work on IOS.
